# Windows RT fails to build after upgrade to Windows 8.1 project

Tags: linker, windows-8.1, msvcrt, windows-rt

I upgraded my Windows RT 8.0 project to target Windows RT 8.1 project in Visual Studio 2013, and now it gives me following linking error:

error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'vccorlib_lib_should_be_specified_before_msvcrt_lib_to_linker': value '1' doesn't match value '0' in MSVCRT.lib(appinit.obj)

Any ideas what's this error about?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem after upgrade to 8.1

My project structure was (example):

`project.vcxproj (Consume Windows Runtime Extension: No)
  file1.cpp
  file2.cpp
  application.cpp (Individual file settings: Consume Windows Runtime Extension: Yes)`

So after upgrade from 8.0 to 8.1 in VS2013 I got such error LNK2038
And my solved project structure is:

`project.vcxproj (Consume Windows Runtime Extension: Yes)
  application.cpp
static_lib.vcxproj (Consume Windows Runtime Extension: No)
  file1.cpp
  file2.cpp`

So project with global enabled runtime extension and static library without runtime extension links without such errors.